# Хранение данных. Указатель

Tags: данные

Какой объем памяти можно адресовать 8-ми битным указателем, если минимальный размер адресуемого объекта 2 байта?

Comment: Посчитайте, сколько разных значений укладывается в 8 бит и умножьте на 2 (ответ 512)

Comment: @avp, и это при условии выровненности данных. И того, что в байте 8 бит. Хотя вроде бы байт и есть минимально адресуемое слово.

Comment: @КириллМалышев, тут совершенно не важно, сколько *бит в байте*, если считать, что спрашивают ответ *в байтах*. Важны 8 бит указателя и **размер адресуемого объекта**. Кстати, кроме всем привычных процессоров с побайтной адресацией, есть и другие, которые адресуют только слова  памяти. Были TMS, адресующие 16 и 32-бит слова, БЭСМ-6 с 48-битными словами, CRAY с 64-битными и наверняка много других, о которых я не знаю (или уже не помню)